# Where to find PySide for Qt5.x

Tags: qt, qt5, pyside

I know that the développement of PySide for that version of Qt is stopped, but for some cases, I want to install it.

Where can I download the last developped version of PySide for Qt 5.x ?

Comment: There has never been any official effort to support Qt5 in PySide.

Comment: I already used PySide for Qt5

Comment: You must be thinking of PyQt - there has never been an official release of PySide for Qt5. There are some third-party projects that have started work on getting shiboken to work with Qt5, but I don't think any of them have released a full set of bindings yet.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is PySide2.
This wiki page tracks the progress of PySide for Qt 5.x development and provides further information concerning the effort:
http://wiki.qt.io/PySide2?

If you want to install it on anaconda:
    conda install pyside2